# Input a vector of vectors with io::stdin in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to input a vector of vectors of u32 using the std::io library.
Here is what I did and it obviously doesn't work because the parse method can't turn a String into a Vec:

```
fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let input: Vec<Vec<u32> = match input.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => vec![vec![0]],
    };
}
```

If you have another way to make it work I'll be happy to try it :)

Comment: can you post an example of the input?

Comment: I would like to input a Vec frame by frame with a Vec of u32, for instance input that:
[0, 1, 5]
and put it in input[0] then that:
[2, 8, 3]
and put it in input[1] etc..

Comment: @DisaroSkeli, maybe you should use some readable format like json for that? where does the input come from?

Comment: @Netwave I'm a beginner in Rust and coding overall so I don't know much about json file and I test my programs through the terminal

Comment: no problem. Just put a specific example of the input. Imagine it is a file for example.

Comment: @Netwave I'm sorry but I have no clue about how JSON files work and how to use them with Rust

Comment: so just show use an example of the input. Whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

For an input of the stile:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

You could use something like the following example. Notice the use of [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html)

```rust
use std::io::BufRead;


fn read_input() -> std::io::Result<Vec<Vec<u64>>> {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let mut lines = stdin.lock().lines();
    let mut res = Vec::new();
    while let Some(line) = lines.next() {
        let line = line?;
        let items = line
            .split(" ")
            .map(|n| n.parse().expect("an u64 parseable number"))
            .collect();
        res.push(items);
    }
    Ok(res)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ec169471ec59cedd50c137724942538a)

Comment: It seems to work but the compiler asks me for ints until I input something else and it panicks :/

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead?